# Creating an AWS CRON String Which Would Run Daily for Selected Days

Tags: cron

What AWS CRON string can be for daily runs with certain days selected days and be schedule for different times?

For example:
Daily at 12:40 and 14:30 for Sun and Wed.

AWS cron is different than cron in crontab files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set records like:

```
40 12 * * 1,2,4,5,6 *
30 14 * * 3,7 *
```

Comment: Thank you, can it be in single expression?

Comment: @Marina, don't have experience with AWS cron, but based on linux cron - no, you can't merge them

Comment: I have example like 20 11,12,13,14 ? * 1,5 *
Does it mean that it will run at 11:20, 12:20, 13:20, 14:20 ?

Comment: Right. And will run Monday and Friday only @Marina